# for some reason, when i compile and try to run the program, the sum doesn't add up right

Tags: java, max, average, min

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    double sum = 0;
    int count = 0;
    double userEnterNumber = 0;
    double min = 0;
    double max = 0;
    double average = 0;
    System.out.println(" Input a number, type a non-numerical value to exit: ");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    userEnterNumber = in.nextDouble();

    while ( in.hasNextDouble())
    { 
        userEnterNumber = in.nextDouble();
        if (userEnterNumber>0) {
            sum = sum + userEnterNumber;
            count ++; 
            average = sum/count;
            if (userEnterNumber >=max){
                max = userEnterNumber;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(" Sum: "+sum);
    System.out.println(" Count: "+count);
    System.out.println(" Average: "+average);
    System.out.println(" Minimun: "+min);
    System.out.println(" Maximum: "+max);
}
```

I am trying to figure whats going on with my program. Whenever I run it, it gives me wrong sum and wrong count. How can I fix it? How can i also add minimum in here? Thanks

Comment: You're skipping the initial value.  First you get in.nextDouble(), then you say while (in.hasNextDouble()), get in.nextDouble() again - so the first one never got recorded as part of your sum.

Comment: You're throwing away the first `in.nextDouble()` because you immediately call it again in the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Read through your program. You are calling this twice:
`userEnterNumber = in.nextDouble();`
before your 1st stat calculation takes place.

Effectively, this means the first Double you enter is skipped. Do the output numbers make sense now?

In the future, try running your program in the debugger and determining whether each variable holds the correct/expected value at each step.

Comment: Thank you. I deleted the first in.nextDouble(); and it works fine